# React: Unable to start old projects. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I am unable to npm start my old React projects (created in October and before, ex: https://github.com/DebojyotiRoy15/Calculator-app). When I try to do it, I get the following error:
[image]

I have tried various things suggested in stackoverflow to solve this error, like adding a .env file to the root, deleting package-lock, deleting node modules and then installing them. But still this error persists. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to run your app without any issues, check it out here https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-dream-s5w2e. Your error is probably due to some package resolving behavior of Node.JS. Try renaming the `C:\Users\Pavilion\node_modules\babel-jest"`, and if it didn't help then run `npm i babel-jest --save-dev` and reload your app again.